Wix ExePackage payload SourceFile complains about having illegal characters
I have a .exe (dpinst-amd64.exe) file and its contents inside of a sub-folder on my desktop with the name FTDIDrivers_Setup. The contents of this folder are like this shown in the screenshot below.

The DependencyFolder is defined as follows:
<?define DependencyFolder='$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)..\..\target\dependencies' ?>

This is what I am trying in the Bundle.wxs.
<ExePackage Id="FTDIDriversInstaller"
                  SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\dpinst-amd64.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/s /se"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Compressed="yes">
           <Payload Name="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\amd64" SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\amd64" />
           <Payload Name="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\i386" SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\i386" />
           <Payload Name="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\Static" SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\Static" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\dp-chooser.exe" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\dpinst.xml" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\ftd2xx.h" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\ftdibus.cat" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\ftdibus.inf" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\ftdiport.xml" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\ftdiport.inf" />
           <Payload SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\licence.txt" />
      </ExePackage>

Doing so is giving multiple errors. All the errors are kind of similar. What can I try to fix this?

The Payload/@Name attribute's value,
'C:\Users\nandukurusai\Desktop\GITSourceCode\PharmSpec\PharmSpec\Install\FactoryTools_Bootstrapper....\target\dependencies\FTDIDrivers_Setup\amd64',
is not a valid relative long name because it contains illegal
characters.  Legal relative long names contain no more than 260
characters and must contain at least one non-period character.  Any
character except for the follow may be used: ? | > < : / *
".    FactoryTools_Bootstrapper   C:\Users\nandukurusai\Desktop\GITSourceCode\PharmSpec\PharmSpec\Install\FactoryTools_Bootstrapper\Bundle.wxs    19

When I right click on the solution and say open folder in file explorer, it says the current folder is outer level of PharmSpec after PharmSpec from the above screenshot. So I'm trying .\target\Dependencies\FTDIDrivers_Setup\amd64 and still it complains the system cannot find the file specified.

The error indicates that Name should be a relative name but you are providing an absolute path.

I understand. How do I provide a relative path. Should I have to copy that folder somewhere to the wix installer project.

This thing is very similar to what I am trying to achieve but I can't find details about where his folder is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474037/add-a-folder-of-dependencies-for-an-exepackage-in-wix

This is the path on the target system, relative to the ExePackage's executable.

I have used an other solution to fix it. I have created a self extracting exe file using 7zip. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904532/how-do-i-make-a-self-extract-and-running-installer. And it works.
